# Ag Grid default styles hide the grid

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am using v27 in my React app and I am only seeing a grey line, unless I manually edit the styles in the dev tools on the browser. There is a css property of `height:0` which is causing the problem.

edited css:
[image]

default css:
[image]

Now, it's easy enough to override the style and resolve it that way, but **WHY is it like that in the first place?** I am implementing the Ag Grid styles incorrectly?

My implementation is very close to the example. The custom cell render is actually a copy of the `medalCellRenderer` found in the documentation, but with a different name (the plan for this was to prototype an amchart in a cell renderer, hence the name)

full code of the component

```
import React, { useMemo, useState } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';

// import { StockData } from './data'

import AmChartsCellRenderer from './AmChartsCellRenderer'
import GenderRenderer from './genderRenderer.jsx';

export const AgGridWithAmCharts = () => {
    const [gridApi, setGridApi] = useState(null);
    const [gridColumnApi, setGridColumnApi] = useState(null);


    
      const [stockData, setStockData] = useState([
        {
        symbol: 'A',
        name: 'Agilent Technologies Inc. Common Stock',
        lastPrice: '179.28',
        marketCap: 54272119919,
        volume: 971760,
        sector: 'Capital Goods',
        rateOfChange: [1, 2, -6, -7, -2, -7, 3, 4, -3, -8],
      },
      {
        symbol: 'AAL',
        name: 'American Airlines Group Inc. Common Stock',
        lastPrice: '19.37',
        marketCap: 12541258186,
        volume: 20309670,
        sector: 'Transportation',
        rateOfChange: [4, 9, 8, 6, 1, -3, 0, -8, 2, -8],
      }
    ]);

      const [columnDefs, setColumnDefs] = useState( 
          [
            { field: 'symbol' },
            { field: 'name' },
            { field: 'lastPrice' },
            { field: 'marketCap' },
            { field: 'volume' },
            { field: 'sector' },
            { field: 'rateOfChange' },
            { field: 'rateOfChange', cellRenderer: AmChartsCellRenderer }
        ]
      );

      const defaultColDef = useMemo(() => {
        return {
          flex: 1,
        };
      }, []);
      
    const onGridReady = (params) => {
        console.log('rowData', params.rowData);
        setGridApi(params.api);
    };

    

    return (
        <>

            <div style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}>
                <div
                    id="myGrid"
                    style={{
                    height: '100%',
                    width: '100%',
                    }}
                    className="ag-theme-alpine"
                >
                    <AgGridReact
                        rowData={stockData}
                        columnDefs={columnDefs}
                        defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
                        onGridReady={onGridReady}
                    ></AgGridReact>

                </div>
            </div>
        </>

    )
}
```

cell renderer code:

```
import React from 'react';
// import { SparkLineChart } from '../Charts/Lines'

export default (props) => (
  <span>{new Array(parseInt(props.value, 10)).fill('#').join('')}</span>
);
```